# Is Sombra's Translocator invisible when thrown?

Tags: overwatch

I've always wondered on how the Translocator works when you use it while you're invisible, and with Sombra now being able to stay invisible forever and keep her Translocator active forever, how does it work now? Is it invisible until it lands or is it visible the moment you throw it? What do the enemies see?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The translocator itself is **not** invisible while it's in the air, so if you throw it while cloaked the enemy may see that you've thrown it.

Comment: As a side note, it's always worked this way even before Sombra's cloak was updated.  I've been caught out by this before as I cloaked, threw it, translocated and been decloaked by enemy fire because the enemy saw it.  For reference, this was on Volskaya attack where there's the window to the right of the arch; the defending team usually sets up at this arch.